# Textarea will not save entry

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm having a problem saving anything in the textarea

```
<div class="col-lg-18 col-md-18 col-sm-18 col-xs-19"><textarea class="rounded-area form-control" rows="5" name="doc_notes" id="doc_notes" style="width:100%" placeholder=""></textarea></div>


public function updateDocNote($user_id) {
        $doc_notes = $this->request->input('doc_notes','');
        $user = User::whereId($user_id)->first();
        if(empty($user)) return response()->json(['error' => "User not found!"]);

        Trace::log('doc_update_note', $this->request->all(), $user_id);
    }
```

Comment: I see no form here...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Saving the docNote to the user or when the page reloads keeping the input in the textarea?

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I wrote that wrong. Anything typed into the textarea won't save.

Comment: @MikeRodham When the page reloads, keeping the input in the textarea

Comment: Then you want to set the value of the textarea to `value="{{ old('doc_notes') }}"`

Comment: In your controller you can `return back()->withInput();` as shown in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#creating-redirects)